# How to write Overlay for my gsi in a 32bit System

Tags: android, xml, overlay

Am using Infinix Hot 8 (X650B) android 9 vendor with lineage OS 19.1 everything was going fine till I upgraded to 20.0 then I had this wierd color bug(saturation on screen was kind of much) I was told it was an overlay issue but I can't compile one for myself successfully pls help

I follow phh tutorial everything went well till running build.sh then I get error:can't execute 64bit code and I don't have access to a 62bit system for now

Comment: You need to modify the firmware path.  See comment for Mar 3, 2022 https://github.com/lineage-rpi/android_kernel_brcm_rpi/blob/lineage-18.1/arch/arm/configs/lineageos_rpi4_defconfig#L1424  Looks like you may be doing a firmware build which is defaulting to 64 bit mode.